# performance considerations multi language site

Tags: database, database-design, localization

I'm starting a project for a new global website with a lot of information. All this information must be localized. I build quite some sites and most of them are only partial in more than one language, but never did something with so much localization.

Assume we have the following data:

Country, City, Store, Product and Product producer.

In the entities Store, Product and Product producer it is possible to have the data localized. The language of the country is mandatory, but next to that N extra languages can be added. This is used to show the information to people of other countries and also I need to search about this.

My initial idea is to create a parent table per localized table with just an id and maybe some metadata that is non localizable and then create a child table with a reference to the parent table, a country code and the localized fields.

This structure potentially results in joins and thus could have a bad influence on performance. Does anyone has experience with this structure? Are there things I should take into consideration? Is there an other way of doing this better?

Comment: That would work for site localization. (labels of fields etc). This is about content and that would not be the best way. Thanks for the suggestion. What would be interesting from this idea would be loading all language stuff in memory from the database due to the fact that it does not change often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I wouldn't worry about throwing a few joins into the mix performance-wise.  As we say, *premature optimization is the root of all evil.*  Create a clean design first and then worry about performance.

The thing you really need to do is think about exactly what you are localizing and why.  What we do in LedgerSMB is exactly what you are suggesting, namely tables with facts, if you will, and then tables with translations.

The key to keeping everything performing well is to think about reducing the number of actual queries sent back and forth.  it's one thing to run a join that pulls 60 or so strings and then your app processes them.  Performance-wise it's a *lot* worse to send 60 different queries to the db to pull 1 string each.

Also keep your main strings in .po files or the like and use localization frameworks for those.  This isn't an either-or thing.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion brought me back on track. First go with the ideal situation and then go with the nice performance tricks.